# How to create a middleware or how to manage the below route for front end and admin

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router, middleware

How can I manage the url for front and admin panel Via Middleware in Vue.

This is the code I have written in router/index.js file:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes });

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('usertoken') == null ? false : true;
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  //this is for admin
  next('/admin/login')
  next('/admin/home');

  //this is my front URL
  next('/terms-condition');
  next('/home');
  next()
})
export default router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below code it may helps you

/**
 * middleware for authentication
 */

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
// redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('usertoken') == null ? false : true;
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  if (to.meta.portal == 'admin') {
    if (to.meta.auth) {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            next('/admin/login')
        } else if (loggedIn) {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            next();
        } else if (loggedIn) {
            if (user.role_id == '1') {
                next('/admin/home');
            } else {
                next('/');
            }
        }

    }
  } else if (to.meta.portal == 'front') {

    if (loggedIn) {

        if (user.role_id == '1') {
            next('/admin/home');
        } else {
            next('/');
        }

    } else if (!loggedIn) {
        if (to.path == "/admin") {
            next('/admin/login');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
  }
 next()
})

export default router;
```

And you need to create two router files one for front and other for admin:

//front route file will look like

```
export default [{
path: '/',
meta: { auth: false, portal: 'front' },
component: () => import('@/components/layouts/front/main.vue'),
children: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'front-home',
        title: 'Dashboard',
        meta: { auth: false, portal: 'front' },
    }
   ]
}]
```

//admin router file will be like

```
export default [
 {
    path: 'user',
    name: 'users',
    title: 'Users',
    meta: { auth: true, portal: 'admin' },
    component: () => import('@/components/templates/admin/user'),
 }
]
```

Main difference is the portal that defines which portal will access by the respective route.Without portal inside meta it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented is correct

Once the user is successfully logged in , use if else condition to redirect to admin panel, also use Navigation guards given in vue-router

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

This help to prevent the other user to use this url directly